# How to make handbrake use the cpu with less intensity?

Tags: handbrake

I've recently began using HandBrake to process some videos I downloaded to make them lighter. I built a small python GUI program to automate the processing, making use of the CLI version. What I am doing is generating the command according to the video and executing it with os.system. Something like this:

```
import os

def process(args):
    #some algorithm to generate cmd using args
    cmd = "handbrakecli -i raw_video.mp4 -o video.mp4 -O -e x264" #example command
    os.system(cmd)
    os.remove("raw_video.mp4")
```

The code works perfectly, but the problem is the overuse of my CPU. Usually, this takes 100% of CPU usage during considerable amount of time. I use the program CoreTemp to keep track of my processor temperature and, usually, it hits 78 °C.

I tried using [BES](http://mion.faireal.net/BES/) (Battle Encoder Shirase) by saving the cmd command into a batch file called exec.bat and doing `os.system("BES_1.7.7\BES.exe -J -m exec.exe 20")`, but this simply does nothing.

Speed isn't important at all. Even if it takes longer, I just want to use less of my CPU, something around 50% would be great. Any idea on how I could do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Handbrake you can pass advanced parameters so you only use a certain amount of CPU threads.

You can use `threads`, view the [Handbrake CLI Documentation](https://handbrake.fr/docs/en/latest/cli/command-line-reference.html)

When using `threads` you can specify any number of CPU processors to use. The default is `auto`.

The `-x` parameter stands for Advanced settings in the GUI of Handbrake, that is where `threads` will go.

The below tells Handbrake to only use one CPU thread for the Advanced setting:

```
 -x threads=1
```

You can also use the `veryslow` for the `--encoder-preset` setting to help the CPU load.

```
--encoder-preset=veryslow
```

I actually prefer using the `--encoder-preset=veryslow` preset since I see an overall better quality in the encode.

And both together:

```
--encoder-preset=veryslow -x threads=1
```

So formatted with your `cmd` variable:

```
cmd = "handbrakecli -i raw_video.mp4 -o video.mp4 -O -e x264 --encoder-preset=veryslow -x threads=1" #example command
```

See if that helps.

Comment: Reducing the thread count is a good idea, but this is also suggesting `veryslow` will throttle the CPU, reducing heat. That's not what it does at all. It means that encoding will be slower _overall_ — taking _more time_ to complete — in exchange for higher quality at the same bitrate or the same quality at a lower bitrate. See [here](https://handbrake.fr/docs/en/latest/technical/performance.html) where `veryslow` encodes at less than half the speed as `ultrafast` for H.264, thus taking twice as long. If your CPU is overheating, the last thing you want is to make it work hard for _even longer_!

Comment: Good Point.. But this doesn't seem like an issue since the OP hasn't replied back saying his CPU is still overheating. It also depends on the type of CPU, and other factors of your rig, so still not an issue. Running the CPU with lower threads for longer, doesnt mean your CPU will overheat, since it is not doing as much work it would be doing with more threads. That's why handbrake has a preview feature so you can test and monitor your CPU, along with setting the priority level for within the GUI or command line.

Comment: You're assuming a reader will combine the options as you've done here. It is very much an issue because you've stated that `veryslow` will "help with CPU usage" (which is incorrect), so a reader could take that to mean that _only_ using `veryslow` and leaving `threads` unchanged will still be effective at combating heat problems; really it will only make the problem worse. If you were to mention one of the `*fast` presets at the other end of the spectrum that would be one thing, but, in my opinion, `veryslow` has no place in this answer; increasing compression is never going to help with heat.

Comment: if you actually read my answer i state both `thread` and `encoder preset`.. If your so concerned about heat then get a mini fan to cool your computer while it encodes, that is what i do as well and it keeps temps down to nothing. I don't mind extra heat especially when it is mitigated by smaller thread count and by a fan to help cool my computer especially when i want the great quality the `slow` encoder speed provides.

Answer (score 1):

One easy way in **Linux** is to use taskset. You can use the terminal or make a custom shortcut/command.

For example, my CPU has 8 threads but I only want to use 6 for Handbrake.

Just start the program with **taskset -c 2,3,4,5,6,7 handbrake**, this way the threads 0 and 1 will be free to another task/process and the program will run on threads 2,3,4,5,6,7.

[image: Ubuntu]

In **Windows** you can change the Target of the shortcut or use on cmd:
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /C start "" /affinity **FC** "C:\Program Files\HandBrake\HandBrake.exe""

As far as I understand It reads the value backwards for each four bits, it means the first four bits in Hexadecimal are for threads 7-4 (1111) and the second four bits in Hexadecimal are for threads 3-0 (1100). In my case I have a 8 threads CPU and leaving free theads 1 and 0 (see image below).

[image: on Windows]

Comment: None of the above threads bits worked and my CPU was practically melting. This did though!